# Error when parsing json

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I have an MVC app where I am serializing a Dictionary of objects into JSON and then passing the object to the client side view where it needs to be parsed. The JSON object looks fine, but for some reason, when I iterate through it in javascript, it loops character by character. It doesn't seem to matter whether I use a regular for loop or a ranged for. I'm not sure why this problem is happening but I think it has something to do with the fact that it's being passed as a string.

- Do I need to do some extra conversion step before the iteration begins?
- How should this process be done?

The structure for the JSON is below:

```
{
    "Obj1": {
            "Value1": "3454234",
            "Value2": "345643564",
            "Value3": "665445",
            "Value4": "True"
        },
        "Obj2": {
            "Value1": "3454234",
            "Value2": "345643564",
            "Value3": "665445",
            "Value4": "True"
        },
        "Obj3": {
            "Value1": "3454234",
            "Value2": "345643564",
            "Value3": "665445",
            "Value4": "True"
        }
}
```

### EDIT

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
```

Comment: You cannot serialize dictionaries. Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx

More specifically, give the FAQ a look.

Comment: Are you trying to parse the JSON manually, by iterating on the string the server has returned ? Have you tried `JSON.parse` on your JSON string ?

Comment: > regular for loop or a ranged for --> Can we see examples of what you have done in Javascript?

Comment: @MikeViscontini So how should I be serializing the objects and sending them to the client side?

Comment: A plain for.. in.. JavaScript loop with a hasOwnProperty should be fine

Comment: @aurelienshz Just updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the characters of the JSON being iterated one by one because it is a string. The javascript interpreter doesn't know this string contains JSON, and, when asked to iterate over a string with `for`, it iterates over it character by character.

Before being able to work with the object contained in a JSON string as an actual Javascript object, you need to convert your JSON string into an actual object. This is called **parsing** the JSON string and is done with `JSON.parse` :

```
var response = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Then, in order to iterate through each key of your object, you can use the for...in syntax :

```
for (key in response) {
  // work with this key here
}
```

Runnable snippet :

```js
// backticks for multiline string :
var jsonString = `{
    "Obj1": {
        "Value1": "3454234",
        "Value2": "345643564",
        "Value3": "665445",
        "Value4": "True"
    },
    "Obj2": {
        "Value1": "3454234",
        "Value2": "345643564",
        "Value3": "665445",
        "Value4": "True"
    },
    "Obj3": {
        "Value1": "3454234",
        "Value2": "345643564",
        "Value3": "665445",
        "Value4": "True"
    }
}`;

var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);

for(key in jsonObject) {
  console.log(key, '=>', jsonObject[key])
}
```

Comment: Yes, JSON parse needed to be added. I forgot that it needed to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
var objJson = JSON.parse(stringJson);
```

But, I think it's better your JSON to be a array.
Maybe you can change your JSON:

```
   [{
        "Value1": "3454234",
        "Value2": "345643564",
        "Value3": "665445",
        "Value4": "True"
    },
    {
        "Value1": "3454234",
        "Value2": "345643564",
        "Value3": "665445",
        "Value4": "True"
    },
    {
        "Value1": "3454234",
        "Value2": "345643564",
        "Value3": "665445",
        "Value4": "True"
    }]
```

Comment: Indeed, he need to JSON.parse his string. But what about the second part of your answer ? His JSON is an object whose keys are `Obj1`, `Obj2`, `Obj3`, why would it need to be an array ?

Comment: It's true @aurelienshz! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The JSon that you have posted has error. You can copy and post your json on https://jsonlint.com/ to validate.

I am posting the valid json as follows

```
{
    "Obj1": {
        "Value1": "3454234",
        "Value2": "345643564",
        "Value3": "665445",
        "Value4": "True"
    },
    "Obj2": {
        "Value1": "3454234",
        "Value2": "345643564",
        "Value3": "665445",
        "Value4": "True"
    },
    "Obj3": {
        "Value1": "3454234",
        "Value2": "345643564",
        "Value3": "665445",
        "Value4": "True"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every JSON object can be represented as a dictionary where the property name is the key and the value, well the value.

With the JSON sample you can deserialize it like

```
class ObjectJson
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
    public string Value4 { get; set; }
}

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,ObjectJson>>( json );
```

See [.net fiddle sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1gutHe)